# Using the convolution theorem to model two teams' relative chances of winning their remaining games

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, convolution

I have been trying to get my head around a toy problem I made up in order to better understand the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) — the convolution of two signals in the 'time' domain (or probability domain for this problem) is equal to the multiplication of those signals in the frequency domain.

**The problem**

In a sports league (Aussie Rules in my example) there are 2 teams both trying to avoid coming last. In order to avoid coming last, Team A must win at least two more games than Team B.

**Assumptions**

1. Each team's distribution of wins from their remaining games $N=8$ can be modeled using a binomial distribution, using some average chance of winning each game ($\rho_a,\rho_b)$. That is, Team A can be modeled by $w(\rho_a)$ and likewise for Team B.
2. The two teams do not play each other and hence their distributions are uncorrelated.

**Attempted solution**

Using $\rho_a=\rho_b=0.2$ I come up with this distribution for number of wins from $0$ to $8$.

$$w(\rho_a)=w(\rho_b)=\begin{bmatrix}
1.68\times10^{-1} \\
3.36\times10^{-1} \\
2.94\times10^{-1} \\
1.47\times10^{-1} \\
4.59\times10^{-2} \\
9.18\times10^{-3} \\
1.15\times10^{-3} \\
8.19\times10^{-5} \\
2.56\times10^{-6} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I then take the Fourier transforms of both distributions.

$$\mathscr{F}[w(\rho_a)]=W_a$$
$$\mathscr{F}[w(\rho_b)]=W_b$$

Then take the pointwise multiplication of these functions and invert

$$\mathscr{F}^-1[W_aW_b]$$

However, this does not return the expected result. I know from solving this same problem in the probability domain that the distribution of Team A getting more $0$ to $8$ more wins than Team B is

\begin{bmatrix}
2.51\times 10^{-1} \\
2.05\times 10^{-1} \\
1.13\times 10^{-1} \\
4.29\times 10^{-2} \\
1.11\times 10^{-2} \\
1.95\times 10^{-3} \\
2.21\times 10^{-4} \\
1.46\times 10^{-5}\\
4.29\times 10^{-7}
\end{bmatrix}

Which is nothing like what I get from the inverse Fourier transform.

I apologise for the long-winded setup, but can anyone point me in the direction of the flaws in my logic?

Edit:

It seems like I had a couple of problems.

1. I wasn't zero-padding the pdfs in frequency space. To be honest, I'm not sure why I need to do that, but it doesn't work without doing so.
2. Not taking the absolute value of the Fourier coefficients before inverting.

**Code**

Here is the code that got me the answer.

```
import numpy as np
from math import factorial

num_games = 8
a_ave_win = 0.2
b_ave_win = 0.2

# create zero padded arrays for pdfs
team_a_pdf = np.zeros((num_games*2+1))
team_b_pdf = team_a_pdf.copy()

# compute pdf from binomial distribution
for i in range(num_games+1):
    team_a_pdf[i] = a_ave_win**i*(1-a_ave_win)**(num_games-i)*factorial(num_games)/factorial(i)/factorial(num_games-i)
    team_b_pdf[i] = b_ave_win**i*(1-b_ave_win)**(num_games-i)*factorial(num_games)/factorial(i)/factorial(num_games-i)


team_a_fft = np.fft.fft(team_a_pdf)
team_b_fft = np.fft.fft(team_b_pdf)

conv = np.abs(team_a_fft*team_b_fft)

ifft = np.fft.ifft(conv).real
print(ifft[:num_games+1])
```

Comment: Since no one answered yet, there is no need to append an `edit` section. Just refine the question where needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a straightforward approach using the theory you are interested in. You are trying to find the distribution of $Z=X-Y$ where $X$ is the number of wins of team A and $Y$ is the number of wins of team B out of $n\geq 2$ games each team plays. We assume $X$ is independent of $Y$. Once you have found the distribution of $Z$, the probability that A wins at least two more games than B is $P(Z\geq 2)$. We have $Z \in \{-n,...-1,0,1,...,n\}$ a.s. By independence, we compute the Fourier transform of the distribution of $Z$:
$$\begin{aligned}E[e^{i\xi Z}]&=E[e^{i\xi X}]E[e^{-i\xi Y}]=\\
&=((p_a(e^{i\xi}-1)+1)(p_b(e^{-i\xi}-1)+1))^n\end{aligned}$$
Under the further assumption that $p_a=p_b=p$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}E[e^{i\xi Z}]&=(2p(1-p)(\cos(\xi)-1)+1)^n\end{aligned}$$
This function is periodic over $(-\pi,\pi]$ (and purely real, so that you already know that the distribution of $Z$ is symmetric around $0$). So what you seek is
$$P(Z\geq 2)=\sum_{2\leq k \leq n}\underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}(2p(1-p)(\cos(\xi)-1)+1)^ne^{-i\xi k}d\xi}_{=P(Z=k)}$$

Comment: Does this solution use the convolution theorem anywhere?

Comment: @darkgbm: look with attention at $E[e^{i\xi Z}]=E[e^{i\xi X}]E[e^{-i\xi Y}]$. This is the 'multiplication in the frequency domain' part.

Comment: Ok I see. Because $Z = X - Y$, it really is the convolution of $X$ and $-Y$ since they are independent. Therefore, the Fourier Transform of $Z$ is the product of the Fourier Transform of $X$ and $-Y$ by the Convolution Theorem, which leads to the equation you cited.

Comment: @darkgbm a detail: remember we are talking about convolutions of the distributions, not of the rvs themselves

Comment: Would it be more precise to say the convolutions of the probability density (mass) functions of the distributions?

Comment: @darkgbm No it is the same here. 'Distribution' of course meaning the pushforward measures of random variables.